FlashList with drag functionality
I am using FlashList from @shopify/flash-list and hitting blockers when trying to implement the same list with a custom draggable feature to let users drag the rows to reorder the same. Is this possible? Since, wrapping the FlashList inside the PanGestureHandler and Animated.View does not render as FlashList instead renders all the rows.

Is using flashlist absolutely necessary? if not react native draglist is a nice alternative to writing the code yourself https://github.com/computerjazz/react-native-draggable-flatlist/tree/main

Yes, thanks but flashlist is the use case, since the list is very huge.
